# How to add millions of contacts to a segment in mautic

Tags: asp.net, mautic

I have lots of contacts in Mautic. I want to add those contacts to a particular segment in Mautic. Clearly, I cannot add each one of them manually. Is there any API or any job available to do this task? If so then how to implement that in ASP.NET?